# Failing sending notifications using firebase cloud messaging, Python API

Tags: python, android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Reading the Firebase documentation I wrote that Python script in order to send some notifications to my Android app.

```
import firebase_admin 
from firebase_admin import credentials, messaging

#USING ENV VARIABLE: GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS 
app = firebase_admin.initialize_app()

topic = 'uat-test' 
notification = messaging.Notification(title="Title", body="Body")

# See documentation on defining a message payload. 
message = messaging.Message(
    notification=notification,
    topic=topic, )

# Send a message to the devices subscribed to the provided topic. 
messaging.send(message)

# Response is a message ID string. 
print('Successfully sent message:', message)
```

The auth information are stored into GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS env variable that point to the private key json file I downloaded from firebase.google.com.

Even if I get as output the message ID and no error message is shown, I don't see any notification on my phone. I successfully get the notification only if I manually send it using the Firebase console through the web app (firebase.google.com) but I need to automatize the process. The notification coming when manually dispatched tells me that my app successfully subscribe to the topic, but I can't get why the Python API doesn't work. I don't think is an environment problem since I had a try with the Node API too and I get the same results. Anyone has some clue ? I feel that I'm missing something. I run the script from my computer, I don't know if it is something that can count.

Comment: Perhaps you can look into my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65377912/pushing-notification-to-all-users-in-firebase/70232919#70232919

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to show notifications. It turn out that since I'm developing using Flutter Framework, the Android app can handle notifications only through the *legacy app server protocols*: [Firebase documentation legacy protocol](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message?hl=it#send-messages-using-the-legacy-app-server-protocols)

Using that approach the notifications are finally shown. I don't know if there will be the same problem with iOS.